# Android app performance issues while loading large data's to recycle view

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

i'm building an android app for a whole sale store.There is a windows application which stores all the product and customer information to the database.Android app suppose to used by the sales representative to take the order from the customer.There is a web service which provide data from the db to android app.
 My problem is, there will be huge number of products(around 5 to 10 K) storing and loading all the data locally and fetching it causes app to close sometimes and some performance issues.I want a solution to solve this problem.

Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Implement infinite scroll instead of loading large data at once.

Comment: How do I do that??

Comment: You can search yourself, its available online.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try to implement pagination in your service like first service will return 100 record and on below scroll recall service for further record from server

Comment: Yeah that's a good choice but the problem is that they want their app to work locally even though there is no net connection they want to see the products and need to take the order.When the app goes online all the orders submitted. Thank you for your feedback.

Comment: @AbhilashC in that case you have to maintain two object. 1 load all data in one object but do not bind it with UI and in second object add some data from first object and display data. after click load more re add data to second object . eg if you have 100 record than add 10 record from object 1 to object 2. on load more add 11 to 20 record in second object this way you app work fine